# Shall I give my secondary router a reserved IP through DHCP or ARP?

Tags: wireless-networking, dhcp, qos, ssid

My primary router [192.168.100.2] has DHCP enabled through the addresses 192.168.100.3 to 192.168.100.200 - I have installed a wireless range extending router [192.168.100.3] with the same SSID at another point in the house. All devices connecting to the secondary router shall automatically use DHCP server of the primary, a default mode of operation. I set the same SSID for both router so the devices can connect to the nearest AP by themselves.

For the purpose of QoS, shall my secondary router get a static IP through ARP of the main router or DHCP address reservation? Does it matter?

I'm asking this because since the time SSIDs were different, the secondary router worked fine while getting an IP through DHCP reservation. But ever-since I've set them to same SSIDs, the secondary router at odd times often does not connect to internet.

Comment: the line "For the purpose of QoS, shall my secondary router get a static IP through ARP of the main router or DHCP address reservation" is non-sensical - you don't get a static IP through ARP, you assign it statically.  ARP is a mechanism used to communicate to other devices in the same subnet+lan to find directly attached machines - ARP does not assign IP addresses.

Comment: It does not matter much whether you assign the IP dynamically via DHCP or statically, but it is easier to maintain a router whos IP address is statically assigned - because you know what it is and its not dependent on another router.